# Lua POST request contains garbage

Tags: lua, http-post

I'm trying to send a POST request but noticed the endpoint I'm trying to access doesn't seem to like the request, so to investigate the situation I redirected the request to `localhost` while listening with `nc` and saw the following request:

```
nc -vlp 444

Connection from 127.0.0.1:53812
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4444
TE: trailers
Cookie: 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: close, TE
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0

27 -- this line shouldn't be there
username=username&password=password
0  -- also this one
```

The code I'm using, just in case:

```lua
local http = require("socket.http") -- even tried ssl.https

...

function Session:post(url, payload) -- payload = "username=username&password=password"
    local response = Response
    local body = { }
    local r, c, h, s = http.request{
        url = url,
        method = "POST",
        sink = ltn12.sink.table(body),
        source = ltn12.source.string(payload),
        headers = {
            ["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0",
            ["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form"
        },
    }
    -- you can ignore this
    response.code    = c
    response.status  = s
    response.body    = table.concat(body)
    self.cookies:parse(h["set-cookie"])
    return response
end
```

Thinking it was a problem of `ltn12` I copied the source code of it directly in my project but soon found out it only returned the payload without actually changing anything

```lua
BLOCKSIZE = 2048
function generate_payload(s)
    if s then
        local i = 1
        return function()
            local chunk = string.sub(s, i, i+BLOCKSIZE-1)
            i = i + BLOCKSIZE
            if chunk ~= "" then return chunk
            else return nil end
        end
    else return source.empty() end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix the issue by adding the `Content-Length` header.